# Remove the space in x axis because of no value

Tags: matplotlib

Below plot is done using "***matplotlib***". I am trying to remove the white space in the x axis. i.e. at 2 in the xaxis.
[image]

My x-axis is day and y-axis is count, On day 2 no count, it is showing blank space,  need to remove this from plot. Code shown below

```
x=Covox_Call["Day"]
y_1=Covox_Call["Cumilative Contacted"]
y_2=Covox_Call["Not Contacted"]
plt.bar(x,+y_1,label="Contacted")
plt.bar(x,-y_2,label="Not Contacted")
plt.xticks(Covox_Call["Day"])
```

Comment: The code you provided is neither complete nor verifiable, in the sense that you can not copy-paste the code to reproduce the error. `Covox_Call` is missing. Please provide atleast some dummy data to make your example work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for further information.

Comment: Covox_Call["Day"] = [1,3,4], Covox_Call["Cumilative Contacted"] = [31,111,156],Covox_Call["Not Contacted"] = [688,608,563], Hope this info() will help you. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is not to use the `"Day"` as the x-value but only for the labeling. The values are just consecutive values (`np.arange(...)`):

```
Covox_Call = pd.DataFrame()

Covox_Call["Day"] = [1,3,4]
Covox_Call["Cumilative Contacted"] = [31,111,156]
Covox_Call["Not Contacted"] = [688,608,563]

x=np.arange(Covox_Call["Day"].shape[0])
y_1=Covox_Call["Cumilative Contacted"]
y_2=Covox_Call["Not Contacted"]
plt.bar(x,+y_1,label="Contacted")
plt.bar(x,-y_2,label="Not Contacted")
plt.xticks(x, Covox_Call["Day"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using the pandas plotting methods based on matplotlib:

```
Covox_Call["Not Contacted"] = -Covox_Call["Not Contacted"]

Covox_Call.plot(x='Day', kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

creates:

[image]